# Count Carriage Returns or Line Feeds in a String in Dart

Tags: dart

I need to count the number of CR or LF or LF + CR in a String.
I'm doing this:

```
String content = "\r dasdsad \r asdasdasd \r";
int count = content.allMatches('\r').length;
print('count: $count');
```

But I get always zero as count value.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to inverse `'\r'` and `content` :

```dart
String content = "\r dasdsad \r asdasdasd \r";
int count = '\r'.allMatches(content).length;
print('count: $count');
```